# Vuetify: move importing base styles from default preset to project when using tree shaking

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When using treeshaking in Vuetify, the [guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#manually-importing) tells to import Vuetify from `vuetify/lib` which imports styles by itself after the styles that my project is using which breaks them and forces me to fight for CSS specificity with less readable CSS code or `!important`.

How can I use tree-shaking and import styles myself after styles that I'm already using at the same time?

Comment: Does this help you?
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#required-styles

Comment: no, it does not, the default preset is still loaded

Comment: Do you use nuxt?

Comment: no, vue-cli 4, not nuxt